# Batch creation of hive tables using python's subprocess module in a for-loop

Tags: python, hive, subprocess

I have an inputList which has tablenames to be created , this list could have 2000 names.

for e.g:

```
inputList = ['model_0001', 'model_0002', 'model_0003', ..., 'model_1000']
```

I'm creating a lot of hive tables using the following python code involving the subprocess module, right now i have to babysit the process and change the list parameters passed to the for-loop( see the 0,20 in the code) . The hive table creation process is submitted to the hive cluster and it runs these processes in parallel. I want to control it using a parameter , how many parallel table creation processes can be submitted. Then the code can run without any intervention.

I also want that if 20 jobs are submitted and 1 gets complete, the next one gets kicked off, essentially at any point only 20 jobs are running.

```
createTablecmd2 = "CREATE TABLE {tableName}_modified AS SELECT k.{tableName}, col2  FROM  {tableName} as d  left outer join table3 as k on d.col4 = k.col4 "


## Creating tables from 1 to 20, inputList[0] corresponds to model_0001 and inputList[19] corresponds to model_0020

for currTable in inputList[0:20]:    
    sqlstmt = createTablecmd2.format(tableName = currTable)
    cmd3 = "hive -e '{stmt}'".format(stmt = sqlstmt)
    print "submitting command", cmd3
    %time result = subprocess.Popen(cmd3, shell = True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem about 95% using the .wait() object in subprocess.

```
inputList = ['model_0001', 'model_0002', 'model_0003', ..., 'model_1000']

import subprocess
batchsize = 20

createTablecmd2 = "CREATE TABLE {tableName}_modified AS SELECT k.{tableName}, col2  FROM  {tableName} as d  left outer join table3 as k on d.col4 = k.col4 "

for currTable in xrange(0, len(inputList),batchsize):
    batch = inputList[currTable:currTable+batchsize]
    for i in batch:
        sqlstmt = createTablecmd2.format(tableName = i)
        cmd3 = "hive -e 'use dbname2; {stmt}'".format(stmt = sqlstmt)
        print "submitting command", cmd3
        %time result = subprocess.Popen(cmd3, shell = True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    result.wait()
```

After the inner for-loop is done, the process waits for the child process to complete and then kicks off another batch of hive jobs. This is not 100% what I wanted, but it serves my purpose currently. Its a synchronous solution.  For e.g. if the batch consists of model_id_0020 .to... model_id_0040 , it would wait for the last process , i.e., model_id_0040 to complete before kicking off the next batch of hadoop/hive jobs.  But lets say model_id_0040 ( the last in the current batch) completes before 3-4 other jobs, it will kick off another batch. So it can be asynchronous in this case.

Hadoop/hive jobs as we all know can finish at different times, even though it is the exact same process with the same table structure being replicated in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The essential question is are you running on Yarn or standalone. If you are running with Yarn, take a look at the cluster manger. It is possible that your cluster is oversubscribed. 
Add more details on the environment. If on yarn look at the job history server to see the details on the job. It will tell you what is happening. Add more details on your environment.

Comment: I'm running this on a yarn cluster.  I want a method where I can fire off job synchronously or asynchronously.